# Template driven forms with components

Tags: angular

How to add template-driven control to ngForm?

For example I have form with two components:

```javascript
@Component({
    selector: 'parent-form',
    template: '<form #form="ngForm">
      <input required [(ngModel)]="model.foo" name="foo">
      <child-form [model]="model"></child-form>
    </form>',
    directives: [ REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, ChildFormComponent ]
})
export class ParentFormComponent {
    public model: MyModel = new MyModel();
}

@Component({
    selector: 'child-form',
    template: '<fieldset>
      <input required [(ngModel)]="model.bar" name="bar">
    </fieldset>',
    directives: [ REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES ]
})
export class ChildFormComponent {
    @Input() public model: MyModel;
}
```

How to add "bar" control from "child form" to "form" in "parent form"?

Update: I found similar [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9600).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As hotfix you may use "RegisterFormModelDirective":

```javascript
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[registerForm]'
})
export class RegisterFormModelDirective implements OnInit {
    private el: HTMLInputElement;

    @Input('registerForm') public form: NgForm;
    @Input('registerModel') public model: NgModel;

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.el = el.nativeElement;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.form && this.model) {
            this.form.form.addControl(this.model.name, this.model.control);
        }
    }
}
```

And this directives:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myValue" minlength="10" #myInput="ngModel" #myComp
  name="childValue" [registerForm]="form" [registerModel]="myInput">
```

See plunkr demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/GG2TVHHHGbAzoOP5mIRr?p=preview

If you have "EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'", change code:

```javascript
public ngOnInit() {
    if (this.form && this.model) {
        this.form.form.registerControl(this.model.name, this.model.control);
        this.form.addControl(this.model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note to Alexey's answer, you should add OnDestroy handler to deattach the input from form control. This is especially required if you're using the input with *ngIf.

```js
public ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.form && this.model) {
        this.form.removeControl(this.model);
    }
}
```